# How to remove duplicate rows containing array in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to delete duplicate rows from my dataset, but there are some rows as array. And when I delete these duplicate rows, the structure of the dataset is not kept originally. I show my dataset, this is in google big query.

[image: dataset colum]

In total, average, percent are more rows. thanks you!.

delete duplicate rows from my dataset

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like total, average and percent are just records/structs, but the mode is not `REPEATED` so they are not arrays, no?

Comment: Sorry, yes!, average and percent are just records structs

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin Weitzmann that the mentioned values are just records and not Arrays. To remove duplicates in these, flatten the nested fields, remove the duplicates, and then re-nest the data.

```
WITH Flattened AS (
  SELECT
    teamId,
    competitionId,
    seasonId,
    roundId,
    matchId,
    total.value AS total_value,  -- Replace 'value' with actual field names
    average.value AS average_value,
    percent.value AS percent_value,
    ... -- Any other fields you need
  FROM
    your_dataset.your_table,
    UNNEST(total) AS total,
    UNNEST(average) AS average,
    UNNEST(percent) AS percent
),
Deduplicated AS (
  SELECT
    teamId,
    competitionId,
    seasonId,
    roundId,
    matchId,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<value STRING>(total_value)) AS total,  -- Re-aggregate the nested data
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<value STRING>(average_value)) AS average,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<value STRING>(percent_value)) AS percent,
    ... -- Any other fields you need
  FROM
    Flattened
  GROUP BY
    teamId,
    competitionId,
    seasonId,
    roundId,
    matchId
)
SELECT * FROM Deduplicated
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Priyas , I can't test the code in your answer, I deleted the table, but now I have to extract it again, so I'll try to tell you.

Comment: I found another way to remove duplicates, I don't know if it will be the best but it works:


WITH ranked_data AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY teamId, competitionId, seasonId, roundId, matchId ORDER BY teamId) AS row_num FROM your_dataset.your_table ) SELECT teamId, competitionId, seasonId, total, average, percent, roundId, matchId FROM ranked_data WHERE row_num = 1;